# Input value clear - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am trying to clear the input after the button click using useRef below is my code

> After button click I cleared the state and the input value

```
    const [giftCode, setGiftCode] = useState('');
    const inputGift = useRef(null);
    const clickHandler = () =>{
       setGiftCode('');  
       inputGift.current.value = '';
     }

                        <TextInput
                            type="text"
                            field="gift-card-code"
                            ref={inputGift}
                            autoComplete="off"
                            onChange={event => {
                                setGiftCodeError(false);
                                setGiftBalanceCheck(null);
                                setGiftCode.bind(event.target.value);
                            }}
                        />
```

The input value is clearing, but the state showing the browser debugger is not changing, if we changed the input filed then the state is changing, useState setGiftcode is not changing the component actual state is there any alternate way to do this. see the below image for the understanding.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code for clicking on the button?

Answer (score 2):

Why not instead of using ref. Assign your state as value in your input?

```
    const [giftCode, setGiftCode] = useState('');
    const clickHandler = () =>{
       setGiftCode('');  
     }

    ...
        <TextInput
             type="text"
             field="gift-card-code"
             value={giftCode} // this
             autoComplete="off"
             onChange={event => {
                    setGiftCodeError(false);
                    setGiftBalanceCheck(null);
                    setGiftCode.bind(event.target.value);
              }}
         />
```

Comment: I have tried the above first but this is not working

Comment: and also if you do the same why the component state didn't change after the setState called I didn't understand why this happening any answer for this!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define `value` as well to input fields to clear after submission.

```
<TextInput
 type="text"
 field="gift-card-code"
 ref={inputGift}
 value={giftCode}
 autoComplete="off"
 onChange={event => {
 setGiftCodeError(false);
 setGiftBalanceCheck(null);
 setGiftCode.bind(event.target.value);
 }}
/>
```

and just clear by defining as you have done already.

```
const clickHandler = () =>{
       setGiftCode(''); // this needs value attribute to input element for clearing 
     }
```